# Who served as an inspiration for the character of Saffron?

Tags: firefly

The character [Saffron](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Saffron) appeared first in the sixth episode, *Our Mrs. Reynolds* and made [quite an impression](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66681/what-is-the-earliest-reference-to-a-poisoned-lipstick-in-a-work-of-science-ficti) on the captain and crew of *Firefly.*

[image: saffron - firefly]

Was she Whedon's spin on the classic *femme fatale* trope, or was she based on a specific [historical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucrezia_Borgia) or litetary figure?

Comment: Also known as Mrs Malcolm Reynolds.

Comment: She's not based on anyone in partiuclar.  Read this (Champs and Tramps): https://tinyurl.com/y95pmwfb

Comment: @Tim so you're saying Saffron is whedon's didactic storytelling tool, created after reading too much Plato? Care to write an answer?

Comment: Nah, I'm not versed enough in ancient Greek philosophy nor have that much knowledge of Whedon's interests at the time.  Just suggesting (from my experience of Whedon's work) that she's likely to be a mixture of tropes with a bit of philosophy thrown in.

Comment: @Tim yeah, that could be the case.